# Does Payflow pro can be used through new REST APIs or they are two different service?

Tags: api, rest, payflowpro

I am researching how to move Classic APIs Payflow pro to used new REST APIs.
Does Payflow pro can be used through new REST APIs or they are two different service?
How to get REST API CREDENTIALS for a Merchant account or add "service" in PayPal Manager?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

The REST API's are currently only available to PayPal accounts. Payflow merchants cannot use them at the moment. I don't know if there are plans to expand them to Payflow either. There is a big push on giving the REST API's the same functionality as all of original PayPal APIs.

There may be something in plan for adding REST functionality to Payflow after all the features are added to PayPal but it wouldn't be for a long time.